# Angular Service Factory with Parameter and a Success Callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The syntax required to pass a parameter breaks the success callback. answer is the parameter. I can get the success callback to work when not using the extra block query: function(answer) {

```
Answer.query(answer, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Here is the service

```
.factory('Answer',function($resource, $cookies) {
return {

query: function(answer) {

  return $resource('/api/answers/', {'question_id': $cookies.question_id, 'answer': 'test'},
      {
         query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false}
  }).query();

}
```

}
})

Here is the Answer. Thank you Gordon Bockus and Grundy. This saved me a lot of time.

Answer.query(answer);

```
.factory('Answer',function($resource, $cookies) {
return {

query: function(answer) {

      return $resource('/api/answers/', {'question_id': $cookies.question_id, 'answer': answer},
      {
        query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false}
      }).query(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      });

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: try `'answer' : answer`

Comment: Thanks. It's just a mock. I am looking into something called promises.

Comment: promises are the way to go.  Much clearer then the sets it when it gets back of $resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing parameters to the factory query function not the resource query function.  If you want to keep the same structure you need to update the your factory

```
.factory('Answer',function($resource, $cookies) {
return {

query: function(answer, callback) {
  var result; 
  return result = $resource('/api/answers/', {'question_id': $cookies.question_id, 'answer': 'test'},
      {
         query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false}
  }).query(function() {
    callback(result);
  });

}
```

check out the example credit card resource on this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource